# Site favicons shifted on the profile page and communities list

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, favicon

Site icons on my [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current) look wrong. (You won't see those icons on my page, so the link leads to yours).

Looks like they're cut from a single long image and the "cutting frame" is shifted down a little.

> [image]

```
   ^^^ here and here  ^^^
```

This doesn't happen on Meta SE but does on SO, ru.SO, sqa, etc. The same problem is in the communities dropdown list:

> [image]

OS X, FF 47.0, userscripts switched off, cache cleaned.

---

Same reported on Meta SO: [Favicons on Hot Network Questions are off center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328274/2790048)

---

I'd changed link to all.css manually, but the problem persists.

[image]

Comment: If you look at the page source, what's the full URL for the .favicon background image?

Comment: @AdamLear: http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite32.png?v=df4c1382a05c

Comment: Hmm. That should be correct. How about all.css? What's the full URL you get for that?

Comment: @AdamLear: on meta ru.so it is http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/rumeta/all.css?v=f439417552e3

Comment: Yeah, that's wrong. Does replacing the query string with `v=dd352e809571` fix the icon display? If so, something on your end is still loading an older version of the styles. A hard refresh might help... although if you've already cleared cache, I'm not sure off-hand why this would be happening.

Comment: @AdamLear I've changed the link in inspector, but to no result. Dropped the cache again, too.

Comment: @AdamLear same in Chrome  51.0.2704.103 (64-bit)

Comment: No repro in Chrome 53-ish

Comment: Looks like our CDN was serving stale content in some regions. Should hopefully be resolved now... Try again and let me know? Thanks!

Comment: @AdamLear please have a look at http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3494. As far as I know, you're the only SE developer who knows Russian and can understand the bugreport :)